# Create a Scalar Chart in Weights & Biases using python

Tags: wandb

I'm using weights & biases and try to log some scalars using python SDK for W&B, the logs appear like that:
[a plot with a single dot I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntNdc.png)

So I basically just run this:
`wandb.log({"loss": 0.5})`

And looks weird, In the UI there's an opttion of creating a Scalar Chart, that you can create by pressing "add panel" and then choose "scalar chart". It looks like this:
[Scalar Chart made in W&B UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiC4q.png)

So I'd like to know if there's a way of creating these scalar charts programmatically using SDK for python?

Answer (score 0):

You can't programmatically trigger Scalar charts in the W&B workspace, but you can log them programmatically to W&B Reports

https://docs.wandb.ai/guides/reports/edit-a-report

See the `ScalarChart` class in this colab for how to log to it

https://colab.research.google.com/github/wandb/examples/blob/master/colabs/intro/Report_API_Quickstart.ipynb#scrollTo=ied4LBFHkJdE

Hope this helps!